# 90 degree elbow for water inlet

Tags: plumbing, vanity

First time poster here.

My wife and I bought a bathroom vanity that came pre-fitted with a hole in the back for the water inlet and drain pipes. But the two water inlet pipes don't fit within the hole in the back of the vanity. The hole is something like 5.5" but the two valves (coming off the H and C inlets) are more than an inch wider than the hole. [Insert comment about measuring twice and cutting once.]
I'm wondering if there is a way to put a 90 degree elbow at the end of the water inlet pipes and connect the valves to the ends of the elbows so that the valves are facing each other and a bit closer together.

That's my idea anyway. If there is a better/smarter/more efficient way I'd love to hear it.

TIA for the help!

Comment: Can you enlarge the hole in the vanity? Oh yes, measure twice and cut once. :-) (I always mix that up)

Comment: Need pictures of what you are talking about.

Comment: If you mean the holes in the back for the water supply, you would just cut new holes. AFIK there is no standard for the position if those holes. You do not need 90 deg elbows. The lines come straight out of the wall and a 90 deg shut-off valve is attached to each pipe. From these flexible lines go to the lavatory faucet. Sometimes the flex lines are part of the faucet, bus usually they are a separate item. Look at videos for installation of a vanity and lavatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the "hole pre-fitted" the job of a vanity is to go over the pipes you have, so just cut  larger or additional holes in the back of it until it fits your actual pipes.